# re sub escaping a potential parenthesis in text

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

The script takes a BeautifulSoup object and replaces the links (usually shortened links) with the final destination URL. It works great but hit a stumble with an error where the hyperlinked text contains (, throwing an error `re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0` is there an easy fix I'm missing that won't alter the text.

```
text = b.get_text()
for link in b.find_all('a'):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        repl = link.get_text()
        href = link.attrs['href']
        link.clear()
        link.attrs = {}
        link.attrs['href'] = unshorten_url(href)
        link.append(repl)
        # below fails if repl contains "("
        text = re.sub(repl+r"(?!= *?</a>)", str(link), text, count=1)
```

Comment: Please edit your question with a couple of example of good and problematic `link`s.

Comment: `re.escape()` is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that by merging a string w/ an RE expression, characters in the string that are also used in RE were triggering errors. The solution was `repl = re.escape(repl)` to add escape characters in front of strings like this, then clean up the text later. Thanks JasonHarper!